# How to get modified date & Time of a ftp directory using perl script

Tags: perl, ftp, perl-module

I wrote one Perl script, which will login to ftp Unix server and will check whether files are processing fine in a particular directories. If file got struck more than 10 minutes in those processing directories, it will trigger an alert to my teams mail ID.

This Perl script is running on a windows server through Batch file that was scheduled in Task Scheduler and will run for every 5 minutes.
I can able to get and convert the time of ftp files to my windows server timings. Every thing works perfectly up to now.

Now I got a new requirement that I should check the last modified date of a backup directory in the same ftp server. Initially my idea is to list the files and could get the last received file date (which is similar to the above process I mentioned). But my main constraint is that backup directory will be having almost 1000's of files and listing and getting time is not a good method.

Below is the module which I have used previously for getting the time & date of FTP files.

```
use File::Listing qw(parse_dir);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `stat DIRHANDLE` operation in Perl, when presented the pathname of a directory, presents a array of information about the item. In the array is the modification time.

See [stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html)

You may have to play around with this to get it to work properly, especially if changes occur in subdirectories to the directory upon which you're watching the modification time.

Answer (score -1):

you could use this code to see details of files inside any particular folder:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::FTP;

my ($ftp, $host, $user, $pass, $source_dir);
$host = "your_host_name";
$user = "Your_user_id";
$pass = "Your_password";
$source_dir = "any_source_DIR";
print "Connect in...\n";
$ftp = Net::FTP->new($host, Debug => 0) || die "Couldn't ftp to $host: $@";

print "Logging in...\n";
$ftp->login($user, $pass) || die "Couldn't login to $host: ".$ftp->message;

print "Getting files from \"$source_dir\"\n";
$ftp->cwd($source_dir);

my @files = $ftp->dir();

foreach (@files){
    print "$_ \n";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

(CC)http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=190020

```
my $file_mdtm = $f->mdtm($file) or die "Can't find $file in $dir\n";

my $five_days = 3600*24*5;    # five days in seconds

  if (time - $file_mdtm >= $five_days)

  {

print "$file is more than 5 days old\n";

  }
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.